# Transformation of CDF of multivariate Gaussian random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a $n$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian random variable $x \sim N(0, \Sigma_{n})$ where $\Sigma_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a valid covariance matrix. Assume a "whitened" representation $z = \Sigma_{n}^{-1/2} x$. Presumably now $z \sim N(0, I_{n})$.

**Question**: For multivariate CDFs of the form $F_X(x) = P(X_0 \leq x_0, X_1 \leq x_1, ... X_{n-1} \leq x_{n-1})$, what is the relationship between $F_X(x)$ and $F_Z(z)$ ?

For the 1-dimensional case, it is clear that $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(\Sigma^{1/2} Z \leq x) = P(Z \leq \Sigma^{-1/2}x) = F_Z(z)$. The same logic holds when $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix as each co-ordinate can be treated independently in a similar manner, but it is not clear to me what is the relationship for a general $n$-dimensional covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Any pointers?

Comment: The CDF for $Z$ can be expressed in terms of the $\Phi(\,)$ (the CDF of a standard 1-D normal distribution). The CDF for $X$ usually cannot be, except in special circumstances, and so there is not simple relationship  between $F_X(x)$ and $F_Z(z)$; they are both integrals of related normal densities, but over fundamentally different sets

Answer (score 1):

It is a special case for linear transformations of a random vector.
Generally, let $\bf{x}$ be a random vector with pdf $F_{\bf{x}}(\bf x')$ and let $\bf{z}=Ax$. If $\bf A$ is a positive-semidefinite matrix $\bf{x}\leq x' \iff \bf{Ax}\leq Ax' \iff \bf{z}\leq z' $.  Therefore,
$F_{\bf{x}}(\bf x')=F_{\bf{z}}(\bf z')$.
If $\bf A$ is not a positive-semidefinite matrix it's complicated since the inequality is not satisfied. Since $\Sigma_n$ is a valid covariance matrix it is a positive-semidefinite matrix.